# Preventing the "[YourProgramName] has stopped working" dialog on unhandled exceptions

Tags: winforms, exception, dialog

I have a WinForm application, with some dependencies on an external library that can on occasion cause an exception outside of the running threads context.  As it stands now, this is completely OK behavior ( well, except of course the exception ) and we wired up AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException to simply restart the program.

The only problem is, the [Your Program] has stopped working like the one below, appears:
[alt text http://telcontar.net/store/archive/CrashGallery/images/crash/vista/2007-05-30%20Microsoft%20Register%20Server.png](http://telcontar.net/store/archive/CrashGallery/images/crash/vista/2007-05-30%20Microsoft%20Register%20Server.png)

Is there a way to prevent this dialog from appearing at all, be it in the AppDomain unhandled exception handler or in a config setting, as no end users are going to be reading it and it just holds up resources until it is clicked.

Comment: AFAIK, that dialog is only displayed when your app terminates in an abnormal manner (such as an unhandled exception).  Are you sure your unhandled exception handler is working correctly in all cases?

Comment: Yes and no.  You are correct, the dialog is because of an unhandled exception and yes, *AN* exception handler is not handling it.  However, the code that is excepting is in a WCF Hosted Service and as such, the WinForm app hosting the WCF service ultimately has no control over the exception, except to notice it in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException.  The ideal solution would be to find and fix all the unhandled exceptions, but for now I am happy to just log the exception occured, restart the APP ( and thus the WCF service ) instead of just having the application terminate and hang.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid the WER dialog by preventing your UnhandledException event handler from exiting.  Call Environment.Exit() to terminate your app.

Comment: Thanks, it works when i need to terminate my application. But what should i do if need to restart it? I'm using Application.Restart() but it shows this dialog ([Your Program] has stopped working)...